# PySides2 - Segmentation fault error when adding a QGraphicsItem to QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside2

I'm trying to add a QGraphicsItem to QGraphicsScene but I'm getting the error: [1]    163644 segmentation fault (core dumped)

The code I'm running is the following:

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import ( 
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsItem
)

class Test(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(
        self
    ):
        super().__init__(parent=None)

scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.addItem(Test())
```

The Python version is Python 3.8.13

Version of PySide2 library: 5.15.2.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: You must keep a reference to the scene: `scene = QGraphicsScene(); screen.addItem(Test())`.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it is still not working. Still segmentation fault error

Comment: Is that your actual, compelete code? If so, you must create a QApplication first.